# How Can I add arrays from a for loop together?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, scipy

As the title says, I'm calculating the affects of the product eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix with powers the eigenvalues.

I have a double for-loop. one for the different times and the other for calculating the product of the the eigenvalue and eigenvector

Each result is a 5x1 array.

I want to store them all together and get a 5x10 array, for each t in time(10 of them), there will be 10 rows

```
import scipy.linalg as la
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(5, size = (5,5))

eigvals, eigvecs = la.eig(a)

time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for t in time:
    g = np.zeros(shape=(5,1), dtype=float)
    for val, vec in zip(eigvals, eigvecs):
        b = (val**t)*(vec)
        g = g + abs(b)
```

Comment: For one time, e.g. `t=1`, what does your `for val...` loop produce?  I get a (5,5) array, not the (5,1) you start with.  `eigvecs` is (5,5).  Do you know the basics of accumulating the results of a calculation in a list?  Basic Python?

Comment: it shouldnt give a 5x5 array because 'eigvals, eigvecs = la.eig(a)' is a function from the Scipy module that calculates the eigenvalue and Eigenvector of the matrix 'a', each column of the array is an eigenvector that correspond the respective eigenvalue. [here's a link to the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html)